# use variables in sql query in access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

How to modify below sql query in Access VBA, where 6021, 1, and EachYear are variables.

```
SELECT  & Edgar_Gen.[SIC Code], Edgar_Fin.EntityID, Edgar_Fin.IsANN, Edgar_Fin.[Fiscal Year],
  Formula AS val
FROM Edgar_Fin INNER JOIN Edgar_Gen ON Edgar_Fin.EntityID = Edgar_Gen.EntityID
WHERE (((Edgar_Gen.[SIC Code]) = 6021) AND
 ((Edgar_Fin.IsANN)="1") AND ((Edgar_Fin.[Fiscal Year])="EachYear"));
```

Comment: See: [
Everything About Using Parameters from Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa160564%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: This link doesn't solve the problem, Jiggles32 gave accurate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you are referring to when you're asking to "modify below sql query" for `6021` `1` and `EachYear`, but this is the basic idea and structure of what you seem to be trying to accomplish:

```
Variable1 = 6021
Variable2 = 1
Variable3 = 2018

CurrentDb.Execute "SELECT Edgar_Gen.[SIC Code], " & _
    "Edgar_Fin.EntityID, " & _
    "Edgar_Fin.IsANN, " & _
    "Edgar_Fin.[Fiscal Year], " & _
    "Formula AS val " & _
"FROM Edgar_Fin " & _
"INNER JOIN Edgar_Gen ON Edgar_Fin.EntityID = Edgar_Gen.EntityID " & _
"WHERE ( " & _
       "((Edgar_Gen.[SIC Code]) = " & Variable1 & ") " & _
       "AND ((Edgar_Fin.IsANN) = " & Variable2 & ") " & _
       "AND ((Edgar_Fin.[Fiscal Year]) = " & Variable3 & ") " & _
       ") "
```

Comment: Yes, I was looking for structure. This is what I was looking for.